# Why does printf print a different number for 1.0 vs. 1. when you incorrectly use a format that isn't a float format?

Tags: c, printf

This is a strange behaviour:

```
int main () {
    printf("%d", 1.);
}
```

When compiled (`-Ofast`):

```
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     eax, 1
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.LC0:                       //double
        .long   0
        .long   1072693248
```

The assembly output is identical to the output for `printf("%d", 1.0);` (including any hidden assembler directives on godbolt), except for `printf("%d", 1.);` you get `6225192` and for `printf("%d", 1.0);` you get `-1359453288`. The value is of course printed as 1 when using a float format.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, the compiler can do whatever it wants.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value that's printed has nothing at all to do with the value you pass in the `printf` call, since integer and floating point arguments are passed in separate areas (at least, this is a common convention, and I assume that you're operating on a machine where it's true). When you ask to printf `%d` without passing any integer argument, you get whatever happened to be previously sitting in the space reserved for the first integer argument, which could be anything. It might be deterministic between different runs of the same compiled program (as a result of some C runtime initialization leaving a predictable value in a register, for instance) or it might be dependent on the execution environment or the phase of the moon. You really don't know, and to be honest, this isn't a case where it's worthwhile to figure out exactly *how* that value got there. It's junk, and that's that.

Comment: oh of course. So obvious. It's using an integer register in the calling convention instead, which of course could contain anything, and which is why it keeps changing when you change any other part of the code

Comment: I think the reason for getting the same 2 values for 1. and 1.0 each time when switching between 1. and 1.0 to is maybe because godbolt is producing a cached version of the previous execution result when it detects the source code and compilation flags are the same

Comment: Also, the reason that it contains a different junk value is because the 2nd integer register in the cc in this case `rsi` before the call to `main` or in `printf` could contain a value that is influenced by an *address*, which is something that would change between executions, because it could be a different stack/data section address, especially a different heap address

Answer (score 3):

hobbs has the right answer: it's just garbage, unrelated to the difference between `1.` and `1.0`.

Indeed, you're on x86-64, on which the second integer or pointer argument to any function is passed in the `rsi` register.  So your `printf` prints whatever is in `esi` (its low 32 bits).  Now nothing in `main` modifies `rsi`, so it still contains what it did when `main` was entered; namely, the second argument to `main`, which is the `argv` pointer.
(You didn't declare arguments to `main`, but the startup code passes them anyway, as if you had done `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and maybe a third argument `char **envp`.)

So you're printing the low 32 bits of the address of the command-line argument vector.  If you're on a typical system that uses ASLR, this will effectively be a rather random number (except its low bits).  And it will change from one run of your program to the next, whether or not you modify or recompile the source.

Your floating-point `1.0` or `1.` is in `xmm0` which `printf` ignores completely because you didn't tell it to print a floating-point number.